# How to Convert Swift JSON / Dict Key camel to underscore without Codable?

Tags: json, swift

I want convert:

```
{
  "userNickname": "whatever",
  "userId": "123",
  "date": "2021-03-25T16:10:00Z"
}
```

to

```
{
  "user_nick_name": "whatever",
  "user_id": "123",
  "date": "2021-03-25T16:10:00Z"
}
```

But all the methods found so far are based on the codable protocol, or bugs generated during the conversion process, do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: Note: Do not use Codable Protocol

Comment: Why is this a requirement, please explain.

Comment: Because some json data returned from the server does not need to be modeled before use, it is more convenient for me to directly convert into a dictionary, so I only need to convert the keys in the dictionary into camel format.

Comment: Then your requirement is  maybe incorrect  as you can see from my answer below where I use no custom types but only a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

First decode the json normally and then encode it with a `keyEncodingStrategy` set to `convertToSnakeCase`

Example (with non existing error handling)

```
json = """
{
  "userNickname": "whatever",
  "userId": "123",
  "date": "2021-03-25T16:10:00Z"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let result = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String:String].self, from:json)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.keyEncodingStrategy = .convertToSnakeCase

let data = try! encoder.encode(result)

if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(str)
}
```

Comment: Is this method implemented based on the codable protocol?

Comment: Yes it is since I use JSONDecoder/Encoder

Comment: it's just print {"date":"2021-03-25T16:10:00Z","userNickname":"whatever","userId":"123"}

Comment: Not for me, it works as expected when I run it.

Comment: Anyway, thanks, let me see where the problem is